# differences between "%c" and "%s" in C

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int k;  
    
    scanf("%s", str);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("%c", str[k - 1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Why in command `printf` we have to use `%c` instead of `%s`? I tried replacing `%c` = `%s` but get no result.

Comment: Did you read the [printf man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)?

Comment: sorry im newbie :((

Comment: What input was used?

Comment: Everyone starts as a newbie so no problem with that. But as a newbies it's even more important to read the documentation when you don't understand something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `printf` format string, `%c` expects an `int` representing a single character. `str[k - 1]` is a `char`, which is promoted to `int` when passed to variadic functions such as `printf`.

`%s` expects a non null `char` pointer pointing to a C string.

Note that you can print a single non-zero character with this:

```
printf("%.1s", &str[k - 1]);
```

The precision field after the `.` specifies the maximum number of characters to output, and `&str[k - 1]` is a pointer to the `k`-th character of string `str`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: good point, answer amended. I was expecting a language-lawyer argument about `char` being promoted to `unsigned int` on architectures where `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` (unsigned `char` type and `sizeof(int) == 1`).

Comment: `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` machines live near the worlds of [dinosaurs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215113/29485) and unicorns.